# Usage of a TI DSP EVM and ADC card

Tags: analog-to-digital

I'm not quite sure if I can ask about a vendor-specific hardware here, please teach me if not.

We have a TI's DSP EVM, one of EVMK2Ls (XEVMK2LX/XTCIEVMK2LX) and wanna do some digital signal processing using it.

To get analog signal data, we purchased a 3rd-party ADC EVM, [DEV-ADC34J22](http://www.ti.com/tool/dev-adc34j22), considering necessary specs such as sampling rate and support for the high speed transmission protocol, JESD204B.

The ADC EVM, however, doesn't have a connector for direct connection to the DSP EVM (which has FMC connectors), instead has the HSMC connector only, so we had to buy an adapter card, KY-FMC2HSMC.

Now, we can connect the two EVMs, DSP-EVM and ADC EVM, to each other, but don't know how to use the combination for our purpose. As mentioned above, we want to get data from the ADC and do some processing on them in a programmatic way (in C, more specifically). We posted many questions on the TI's E2E community forum and got some answers, and finally concluded that we can't achieve the goal with the hardware configuration (even if it's theoretically possible, practically not possible for us).

So, now we are considering to purchase another [ADC EVM](http://www.ti.com/tool/adc34j22evm), which seems to be TI's 1st party EVM and to connects to the DSP EVM directly with the FMC connector. It has the same chips (ADC/LMK) made by TI with the ADC EVM we bought, and therefore meets our requirements. We hope we can just use it out of the box.

We got some advices from TI's engineers at the community forum actually, but the options suggested are not affordable for us due to the limited budget. We asked about the TI's ADC EVM we wanna try, but didn't get the answer yet. We came to know this DSP stack exchange site today and would like to get some advice also from experts who is not a TI employee, even though the answers from the TI's engineers were also helpful.

Any other recommendation on the hardware configuration would also be appreciated. We just want to be able to acquire and process a large number of data programmatically as quickly as possible. The number is upto 20M, and we need to do FFT and other transforms on the data using a DSP or anything having enough processing power for that.

Thank you very much!

Comment: So, what is your budget constraint? Do you have latency constraints? What is the application that you want to use this for, in the end? What kind of analog signal are we talking about? What bit depth and noise requirements do you have for the ADC? Your question direly needs more background info; we're not in your lab and especially not in your head! "Want to process much data as quickly as possible" really is not a problem description nor a requirement.